# Ender 3 V2 with new SKR mini e3 v3 is heating up extremely slowly

Tags: creality-ender-3, marlin, skr-mini-e3

I just replaced my motherboard with a new SKR mini e3 v3 and changed the config files myself based on this [Consolidated Marlin Guide](https://www.makenprint.uk/3d-printing/3d-firmware-guides/marlin/consolidated-marlin-guide/).

Unfortunately, It is taking over 10 minutes to heat up the bed which I've never experienced before.  I've checked the voltage going into the motherboard and confirmed it is 24 V. I took a look at the thermistor but I can't tell if that's the issue, I've changed the thermistor on the hotend before and that seemed like a different issue. I'm not sure if there's something in the firmware I missed. (also another problem that's not important but if someone knows the solution that would be great, the stepper motors are quieter than ever which is nice except when homing or leveling, then they sound like

[image: Screenshot of Octoprint' temperature details]

This is the end of one of the bed trying to heat up, I turned the printer off because I didn't want to damage the printer.

```
Recv:  T:36.05 /0.00 B:47.91 /50.00 @:0 B@:24 W:?
Recv:  T:36.15 /0.00 B:48.16 /50.00 @:0 B@:10
Recv:  T:36.02 /0.00 B:48.02 /50.00 @:0 B@:18 W:?
Recv: echo:busy: processing
Recv:  T:36.06 /0.00 B:48.01 /50.00 @:0 B@:19 W:?
Recv:  T:36.04 /0.00 B:48.03 /50.00 @:0 B@:18 W:?
Recv:  T:35.99 /0.00 B:48.07 /50.00 @:0 B@:16
Recv: echo:busy: processing
Recv:  T:36.02 /0.00 B:48.11 /50.00 @:0 B@:14 W:?
Recv:  T:36.06 /0.00 B:48.08 /50.00 @:0 B@:16 W:?
Recv: echo:busy: processing
Recv:  T:35.98 /0.00 B:48.06 /50.00 @:0 B@:17 W:?
Recv:  T:35.92 /0.00 B:48.02 /50.00 @:0 B@:20
Recv:  T:35.95 /0.00 B:48.08 /50.00 @:0 B@:16 W:?
Recv: echo:busy: processing
Recv:  T:35.96 /0.00 B:47.99 /50.00 @:0 B@:21 W:?
Recv:  T:35.92 /0.00 B:48.02 /50.00 @:0 B@:19 W:?
Recv:  T:35.96 /0.00 B:48.09 /50.00 @:0 B@:15
Recv: echo:busy: processing
Recv:  T:35.92 /0.00 B:48.14 /50.00 @:0 B@:13 W:?
Recv:  T:35.99 /0.00 B:48.08 /50.00 @:0 B@:17 W:?
Recv: echo:busy: processing
Recv:  T:36.01 /0.00 B:48.02 /50.00 @:0 B@:20 W:?
Recv:  T:35.92 /0.00 B:48.11 /50.00 @:0 B@:15
Recv:  T:35.92 /0.00 B:48.09 /50.00 @:0 B@:16 W:?
Recv: echo:busy: processing
Recv:  T:35.92 /0.00 B:47.99 /50.00 @:0 B@:22 W:?
Recv:  T:35.93 /0.00 B:47.98 /50.00 @:0 B@:23 W:?
Recv:  T:35.88 /0.00 B:48.03 /50.00 @:0 B@:20
Recv: echo:busy: processing
Recv:  T:35.92 /0.00 B:48.10 /50.00 @:0 B@:16 W:?
Recv:  T:35.87 /0.00 B:48.08 /50.00 @:0 B@:17 W:?
Recv: echo:busy: processing
Recv:  T:35.92 /0.00 B:48.02 /50.00 @:0 B@:20 W:?
Recv:  T:35.91 /0.00 B:48.07 /50.00 @:0 B@:18
Recv:  T:35.91 /0.00 B:48.10 /50.00 @:0 B@:17 W:?
Recv: echo:busy: processing
Recv:  T:35.76 /0.00 B:48.06 /50.00 @:0 B@:19 W:?
Recv:  T:35.89 /0.00 B:48.10 /50.00 @:0 B@:17 W:?
Recv:  T:35.78 /0.00 B:48.12 /50.00 @:0 B@:16
Recv: echo:busy: processing
Recv:  T:35.89 /0.00 B:48.11 /50.00 @:0 B@:17 W:?
Recv:  T:35.80 /0.00 B:48.02 /50.00 @:0 B@:22 W:?
Recv: echo:busy: processing
Recv:  T:35.77 /0.00 B:48.08 /50.00 @:0 B@:19 W:?
Recv:  T:35.78 /0.00 B:48.01 /50.00 @:0 B@:22
Recv:  T:35.79 /0.00 B:48.11 /50.00 @:0 B@:17 W:?
Recv: echo:busy: processing
Recv:  T:35.69 /0.00 B:48.02 /50.00 @:0 B@:22 W:?
Recv:  T:35.68 /0.00 B:48.11 /50.00 @:0 B@:17 W:?
Recv:  T:35.70 /0.00 B:48.14 /50.00 @:0 B@:15
Recv: echo:busy: processing
Recv:  T:35.78 /0.00 B:48.15 /50.00 @:0 B@:15 W:?
Recv:  T:35.66 /0.00 B:48.06 /50.00 @:0 B@:20 W:?
Recv: echo:busy: processing
Recv:  T:35.61 /0.00 B:48.10 /50.00 @:0 B@:18 W:?
Recv:  T:35.71 /0.00 B:48.16 /50.00 @:0 B@:15
Recv:  T:35.77 /0.00 B:48.18 /50.00 @:0 B@:14 W:?
Recv: echo:busy: processing
Recv:  T:35.69 /0.00 B:48.15 /50.00 @:0 B@:16 W:?
Recv:  T:35.58 /0.00 B:48.09 /50.00 @:0 B@:20 W:?
Recv:  T:35.63 /0.00 B:48.06 /50.00 @:0 B@:22
Recv: echo:busy: processing
Recv:  T:35.60 /0.00 B:48.03 /50.00 @:0 B@:23 W:?
Recv:  T:35.66 /0.00 B:48.11 /50.00 @:0 B@:19 W:?
Recv: echo:busy: processing
Recv:  T:35.62 /0.00 B:48.03 /50.00 @:0 B@:23 W:?
Recv:  T:35.58 /0.00 B:48.15 /50.00 @:0 B@:17
Recv:  T:35.61 /0.00 B:48.09 /50.00 @:0 B@:20 W:?
Recv: echo:busy: processing
Recv:  T:35.60 /0.00 B:48.22 /50.00 @:0 B@:13 W:?
Recv:  T:35.67 /0.00 B:48.23 /50.00 @:0 B@:13 W:?
Recv:  T:35.55 /0.00 B:48.13 /50.00 @:0 B@:18
Recv: echo:busy: processing
Recv:  T:35.61 /0.00 B:48.20 /50.00 @:0 B@:14 W:?
Recv:  T:35.49 /0.00 B:48.16 /50.00 @:0 B@:17 W:?
Recv: echo:busy: processing
Recv:  T:35.67 /0.00 B:48.13 /50.00 @:0 B@:19 W:?
Recv:  T:35.53 /0.00 B:48.19 /50.00 @:0 B@:16
Recv:  T:35.68 /0.00 B:48.30 /50.00 @:0 B@:10 W:?
Recv: echo:busy: processing
Recv:  T:35.40 /0.00 B:48.14 /50.00 @:0 B@:20 W:?
Recv:  T:35.71 /0.00 B:48.11 /50.00 @:0 B@:22 W:?
Recv:  T:35.54 /0.00 B:48.18 /50.00 @:0 B@:18
Recv: echo:busy: processing
Recv:  T:35.63 /0.00 B:48.09 /50.00 @:0 B@:22 W:?
Recv:  T:35.58 /0.00 B:48.11 /50.00 @:0 B@:22 W:?
Recv: echo:busy: processing
Recv:  T:35.45 /0.00 B:48.16 /50.00 @:0 B@:19 W:?
Recv:  T:35.60 /0.00 B:48.18 /50.00 @:0 B@:18
Recv:  T:35.48 /0.00 B:48.17 /50.00 @:0 B@:18 W:?
Recv: echo:busy: processing
Recv:  T:35.57 /0.00 B:48.26 /50.00 @:0 B@:13 W:?
Recv:  T:35.48 /0.00 B:48.20 /50.00 @:0 B@:17 W:?
Recv:  T:35.48 /0.00 B:48.23 /50.00 @:0 B@:15
Recv: echo:busy: processing
Recv:  T:35.54 /0.00 B:48.21 /50.00 @:0 B@:16 W:?
Recv:  T:35.35 /0.00 B:48.17 /50.00 @:0 B@:19 W:?
Recv: echo:busy: processing
Recv:  T:35.46 /0.00 B:48.16 /50.00 @:0 B@:20 W:?
Recv:  T:35.58 /0.00 B:48.13 /50.00 @:0 B@:21
Recv:  T:35.38 /0.00 B:48.17 /50.00 @:0 B@:19 W:?
Recv: echo:busy: processing
Recv:  T:35.44 /0.00 B:48.25 /50.00 @:0 B@:15 W:?
Recv:  T:35.35 /0.00 B:48.31 /50.00 @:0 B@:13 W:?
Recv:  T:35.46 /0.00 B:48.18 /50.00 @:0 B@:19
Recv: echo:busy: processing
Recv:  T:35.29 /0.00 B:48.19 /50.00 @:0 B@:19 W:?
Recv:  T:35.38 /0.00 B:48.19 /50.00 @:0 B@:19 W:?
Recv: echo:busy: processing
Recv:  T:35.28 /0.00 B:48.26 /50.00 @:0 B@:16 W:?
Recv:  T:35.38 /0.00 B:48.27 /50.00 @:0 B@:15
Recv:  T:35.38 /0.00 B:48.22 /50.00 @:0 B@:19 W:?
Recv: echo:busy: processing
Recv:  T:35.29 /0.00 B:48.12 /50.00 @:0 B@:24 W:?
Recv:  T:35.38 /0.00 B:48.24 /50.00 @:0 B@:17 W:?
Recv:  T:35.39 /0.00 B:48.29 /50.00 @:0 B@:15
Recv: echo:busy: processing
Recv:  T:35.39 /0.00 B:48.24 /50.00 @:0 B@:17 W:?
Recv:  T:35.39 /0.00 B:48.27 /50.00 @:0 B@:16 W:?
Recv: echo:busy: processing
Recv:  T:35.39 /0.00 B:48.27 /50.00 @:0 B@:16 W:?
Recv:  T:35.36 /0.00 B:48.22 /50.00 @:0 B@:19
Recv:  T:35.29 /0.00 B:48.24 /50.00 @:0 B@:18 W:?
Recv: echo:busy: processing
Recv:  T:35.46 /0.00 B:48.24 /50.00 @:0 B@:19 W:?
Recv:  T:35.27 /0.00 B:48.37 /50.00 @:0 B@:12 W:?
Recv:  T:35.24 /0.00 B:48.29 /50.00 @:0 B@:16
Recv: echo:busy: processing
Recv:  T:35.27 /0.00 B:48.23 /50.00 @:0 B@:20 W:?
Recv:  T:35.24 /0.00 B:48.26 /50.00 @:0 B@:18 W:?
Recv: echo:busy: processing
Recv:  T:35.32 /0.00 B:48.27 /50.00 @:0 B@:17 W:?
Recv:  T:35.32 /0.00 B:48.28 /50.00 @:0 B@:17
Recv:  T:35.33 /0.00 B:48.24 /50.00 @:0 B@:19 W:?
Recv: echo:busy: processing
Recv:  T:35.38 /0.00 B:48.32 /50.00 @:0 B@:15 W:?
Recv:  T:35.27 /0.00 B:48.18 /50.00 @:0 B@:23 W:?
Recv:  T:35.24 /0.00 B:48.34 /50.00 @:0 B@:14
Recv: echo:busy: processing
Recv:  T:35.24 /0.00 B:48.26 /50.00 @:0 B@:18 W:?
Recv:  T:35.22 /0.00 B:48.27 /50.00 @:0 B@:18 W:?
Recv: echo:busy: processing
Recv:  T:35.33 /0.00 B:48.19 /50.00 @:0 B@:22 W:?
Recv:  T:35.26 /0.00 B:48.24 /50.00 @:0 B@:19
Recv:  T:35.33 /0.00 B:48.33 /50.00 @:0 B@:15 W:?
Recv: echo:busy: processing
Recv:  T:35.30 /0.00 B:48.24 /50.00 @:0 B@:20 W:?
Recv:  T:35.21 /0.00 B:48.31 /50.00 @:0 B@:16 W:?
Recv:  T:35.27 /0.00 B:48.29 /50.00 @:0 B@:18
Recv: echo:busy: processing
Recv:  T:35.20 /0.00 B:48.23 /50.00 @:0 B@:21 W:?
Recv:  T:35.18 /0.00 B:48.31 /50.00 @:0 B@:17 W:?
Recv: echo:busy: processing
Recv:  T:35.29 /0.00 B:48.24 /50.00 @:0 B@:21 W:?
Recv:  T:35.07 /0.00 B:48.22 /50.00 @:0 B@:22
Recv:  T:35.14 /0.00 B:48.32 /50.00 @:0 B@:16 W:?
Recv: echo:busy: processing
Recv:  T:35.26 /0.00 B:48.41 /50.00 @:0 B@:12 W:?
Recv:  T:35.21 /0.00 B:48.31 /50.00 @:0 B@:17 W:?
Recv:  T:35.19 /0.00 B:48.33 /50.00 @:0 B@:16
Recv: echo:busy: processing
Recv:  T:35.10 /0.00 B:48.27 /50.00 @:0 B@:20 W:?
Recv:  T:35.14 /0.00 B:48.31 /50.00 @:0 B@:17 W:?
Recv: echo:busy: processing
Recv:  T:35.12 /0.00 B:48.36 /50.00 @:0 B@:15 W:?
Recv:  T:35.15 /0.00 B:48.24 /50.00 @:0 B@:22
Recv:  T:35.11 /0.00 B:48.32 /50.00 @:0 B@:17 W:?
Recv: echo:busy: processing
Recv:  T:35.10 /0.00 B:48.24 /50.00 @:0 B@:21 W:?
Recv:  T:35.06 /0.00 B:48.43 /50.00 @:0 B@:12 W:?
Recv:  T:35.12 /0.00 B:48.36 /50.00 @:0 B@:16
Recv: echo:busy: processing
Recv:  T:35.06 /0.00 B:48.25 /50.00 @:0 B@:22 W:?
Recv:  T:35.04 /0.00 B:48.35 /50.00 @:0 B@:16 W:?
Recv: echo:busy: processing
Recv:  T:35.11 /0.00 B:48.29 /50.00 @:0 B@:20 W:?
Recv:  T:35.13 /0.00 B:48.29 /50.00 @:0 B@:20
Recv:  T:35.11 /0.00 B:48.30 /50.00 @:0 B@:19 W:?
Unexpected error while reading serial port, please consult octoprint.log for details: SerialException: 'device reports readiness to read but returned no data (device disconnected or multiple access on port?)' @ comm.py:_readline:3997
Please see https://faq.octoprint.org/serialerror for possible reasons of this.
Changing monitoring state from "Operational" to "Offline after error"
Connection closed, closing down monitor
Changing monitoring state from "Offline" to "Detecting serial connection"
Performing autodetection with 1 port/baudrate candidates: /dev/ttyACM0@115200
Trying port /dev/ttyACM0, baudrate 115200
Connecting to port /dev/ttyACM0, baudrate 115200
Handshake attempt #1 with timeout 2.0s
Connected to: Serial<id=0x6885ced0, open=True>(port='/dev/ttyACM0', baudrate=115200, bytesize=8, parity='N', stopbits=1, timeout=2.0, xonxoff=False, rtscts=False, dsrdtr=False), starting monitor
Send: N0 M110 N0*125
Recv: Testing X connection... OK
Recv: Testing Y connection... OK
Recv: Testing Z connection... OK
Recv: Testing E connection... OK
Recv: echo:SD card ok
Recv: ok
Changing monitoring state from "Detecting serial connection" to "Operational"
Send: N0 M110 N0*125
Recv: ok
Send: N1 M115*39
Recv: FIRMWARE_NAME:Marlin bugfix-2.1.x (Mar  1 2023 16:28:19) SOURCE_CODE_URL:github.com/MarlinFirmware/Marlin PROTOCOL_VERSION:1.0 MACHINE_TYPE:3D Printer EXTRUDER_COUNT:1 UUID:cede2a2f-41a2-4748-9b12-c55c62f367ff
```